# Angular get parameter from JSON rootscope object

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel

in angular I have a rootscope object like this:

```
{"id":12,"email":"testmail@test.com","given_name":"John","family_name":"Doe","car":"BMW"}
```

How can I acces each parameter individually?

Now I just do

```
{{ currentUser }}
```

And doing

```
{{ currentUser.email }}
```

obviously doesn't work. I'm guessing something is wrong with this JSON object?

Thank you

Comment: It should work..but you should use `$rootScope` for sharing data..do go for service or factory

Comment: are you using `controllerAs` syntax? If not it should work. Provide a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is anything wrong with your json object, check this way to set data on the rootScope. Maybe is helpful for you.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.factory('currentUser', [
    function () {
        return {
            "id": 12,
            "email": "testmail@test.com",
            "given_name": "John",
            "family_name": "Doe",
            "car": "BMW"
        };
    }])
.run([
    '$rootScope', 'currentUser', function ($rootScope, currentUser) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = currentUser;
    }
]);
```

then later you can call `{{ currentUser.email }}` on templates and $scope.currentUser.email on code.

you can update the data on the controllers injecting `$rootScope`.

Comment: Hi, I have worked around my problem by using a factory instead. But what would be better practice? To use the rootScope? Or a factory?

Comment: the current logged user is one of few examples that admit this behavior, I actually use this approach on my apps, when I am defining globals concepts.Example, the current logged user is something that can be available on all the instances of the app, in the scope inself. Is better to maintain the root scope as clean as posible to avoid misunderstandings on the templates. Just keep global concepts on it.